# Bigquery query fails “Resources exceeded during query execution: Table metadata used for the query is too large”

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, legacy-sql

I am hitting the error

> "Resources exceeded during query execution: Table metadata used for
>   the query is too large"

when executing this query:

```
SELECT
  EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(a.id)
FROM (
  SELECT
    id
  FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([*****],
        TIMESTAMP('2019-4-1'),
        TIMESTAMP('2019-4-22')))
  GROUP BY
    id) AS a
JOIN (
  SELECT
    id
  FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([*****],
        TIMESTAMP('2017-1-1'),
        TIMESTAMP('2018-12-31')))
  GROUP BY
    id) AS b
ON
  a.id = b.id
```

If I change `TIMESTAMP('2017-1-1'),TIMESTAMP('2018-12-31')` to `TIMESTAMP('2018-1-1'),TIMESTAMP('2018-12-31')` , it will work. Anything i can do to fix it without change the TIMESTAMP ?

Answer (score 1):

First, why are you using legacy SQL and not standard SQL?

Second, you are aggregating each of the subqueries by `id`, so there are no duplicates.  You don't need to count distinct ids in the outer query `COUNT(*)` does the same thing.  This might fix the problem.

Comment: Why legacy SQL can't work, but standard SQL can? Different limits standard?

Comment: @Evan.Chen . . . Legacy SQL is just what its name implies -- an old version of SQL.  Google has gone through the effort of creating a much more standard-compatible interface with new functionality provided in that interface.  You should use it.